# Mass Transit Auditing sql dbcontext issue

Tags: c#, masstransit, auditing

I'm struggling to understand how to configure mass transit auditing facilitiy.

Reading the following documentation suggests that it needs a DBContextOptions? How does one go about new-ing that up and passing in a connection string?

https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/audit.html#principles

busControl.ConnectConsumeAuditObserver(auditStore);

so i've installed MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCore from nuget

...ConnectConsumeAuditObserver(new ????)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension method to configure it:

```cs
var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();

builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

configurator.UseEntityFrameworkCoreAuditStore(builder.Options, "AuditTableName");
```